# using the strtol function for validation instead of atoi()

Tags: c

I have some code that reads some data from a file, line by line using ":" as the token for each element within the line, It then vaildates the line with a specification and either outputs the code within a file named data.txt or error.txt depending if the file passed validation or not. The code is shown below:

What I am asking is, how would I modify the code where I use the atoi function to use the strtol function instead for better practice in terms of validation.

```
#include <stdio.h>          //library including standard input and output functions
#include <stdlib.h>         //library including exit and system functions used below
#include <string.h>         //library including string functions used

struct packet{
    int source;        // 1 - 1024 range (int)
    int destination;   // 1 - 1024 range (int)
    int type;          // 0 - 10 range (int)               // Varibles for the        structure
    int port;          // 1 = 1024 (int)
    char data[50];     // 1 - 50 range (char)

};

int main()
{

    char filename[32] = { '\0' } ;   // variables which declare the I/O stream and the filename structure
    char DataLine[71];               // Reads the file one line at a time
    char ErrorLine[71];              // This is the varible that deals with the validation error
    char TempStorage[5];                // Stores data to be validated
    char TempData[50];                   // Stores the data which will be validated
    int  TempS, TempD, TempT, TempP;  // Stores the integer derived from the input file
    int  Flag = 0;                   // This is the Flag that indicates a Line has not passed validation
    int  Count = 0;                   // This is the Flag that indicated a line has passed validation
    int  Ecount = 0;                  // This counts the number of errors

    struct packet *DataRecords;
    DataRecords = malloc(sizeof(struct packet));    // This deals with storing the data needed for the next task.

    printf("Enter the filename you wish to open\n");
    scanf("%s", &filename);
                                      // user inputs the filename
    FILE *DataFile;
    if (( DataFile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf ("\nfile could not be opened. : %s\n", filename);  // If a value of NULL is returned then the program will close.

    }
    else
    {
        FILE *ErrorFile = fopen("error.txt","w");                         // This will start searching through the lines and store the lines not passing the validation test to a txt file named "error.txt".
        printf("File has been found, checking validation");

        while( fgets (DataLine, 71, DataFile)!=NULL) {
            strcpy(ErrorLine, DataLine);
            strcpy(TempStorage, strtok(DataLine,":"));
            TempS = atoi(TempStorage);
            strcpy(TempStorage, strtok( NULL, ":"));            // these lines of code looks through each line and stores the line within the "Temp Storage" variable, the : token is what the element within the line is seperated by.
            TempD = atoi(TempStorage);
            strcpy(TempStorage, strtok( NULL, ":"));
            TempT = atoi(TempStorage);
            strcpy(TempStorage, strtok( NULL, ":"));
            TempP = atoi(TempStorage);
            strcpy(TempData, strtok( NULL, ":"));
            strncpy(TempStorage, TempData, 50);                   // security details 

            if (TempS < 1 || TempS > 1024) Flag = 1;
            if (TempD < 1 || TempD > 1024) Flag = 1;
            if (TempT < 0 || TempT > 10) Flag = 1;                   // // Validation aspect, if the validation is not met then a flag is added to which then the line is posted within the error file.
            if (TempP < 1 || TempP > 1024) Flag = 1;
            if (strlen(TempData) < 1 || strlen(TempData)> 50) Flag = 1;
            if (Flag == 1)
            {
                Ecount++;
                printf("Error %i %i:%i:%i:%i:%s",Ecount,TempS,TempD,TempT,TempP,TempData);
                fprintf(ErrorFile,"%s", ErrorLine);
                // fprintf writes formatted text to the output stream you specify
            }
            else
            {
                DataRecords[Count].source = TempS;
                DataRecords[Count].destination = TempD;
                DataRecords[Count].type = TempT;
                DataRecords[Count].port = TempP;
                strncpy(DataRecords[Count].data,TempData,51);
                Count++; //increment sequence number
                DataRecords = realloc(DataRecords,(Count+1)*sizeof(struct packet));//allocate more memory for packet data
            }
            Flag = 0;
        }
        FILE *DFile = fopen("data.txt","w");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            fprintf(DFile,  "%04i:%04i:%04i:%04i:%s",DataRecords[i].source,    // Where the data that has passed validation goes
            DataRecords[i].destination,
            DataRecords[i].type,
            DataRecords[i].port,
            DataRecords[i].data);
        }
        fclose(DFile);
        fclose(ErrorFile);
        fclose(DataFile);
        printf("\nNumber of errors: %i \n", Ecount);
        printf("Number of saved records: %i ", Count);
        free(DataRecords);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is what the data which it reads looks like

```
0002:0004:0002:0010:100000000000000000023
0001:0002:0002:0080:PAGE 1<BR>
0003:0004:0002:0180:100000000000000000026
0004:0004:0002:0180:100000000000000000027
0003:0014:0002:0180:100000000000000000026
```

Comment: start by reading the documentation of strtol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C11 7.22.1.2

> The atoi, atol, and atoll functions convert the initial portion of the
>   string pointed to by nptr to int, long int, and long long int
>   representation, respectively. Except for the behavior on error, they
>   are equivalent to

```
atoi: (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
atol: strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
atoll: strtoll(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
```

So you can replace atoi() with `strtol(nptr, NULL, 10)` everywhere. As for improving error checking, see the documentation of `strtol` and what it returns upon different errors.

Comment: would you mind showing me how I would implement this in my program? quite new to programming so I find this quite hard to understand

Comment: @user3521585 Instead of `TempS = atoi(TempStorage);`, write `TempS = strtol (TempStorage, NULL, 10);` and that's guaranteed to be equivalent. You have to read up on the strol, strtoi etc family of functions to understand why, and to see how to introduce error handling.

Comment: @Lundin they are not equivalent, `atoi` causes undefined behaviour in some cases and strtol doesn't

Comment: @MattMcNabb Hence the cited text "Except for the behavior on error...". Swapping atoi for strtol will not introduce problems in the code.